# Getting error in R.java file

Tags: java, android, layout, r.java-file

I am getting an error in R.java file on some id. Error is ;(semicolon) expected. Can we find out where is it that layout which is showing error?

```
public static final int rd_!=0x7f0e0210;
```

Its showing error on this line.

Any way to delete this.?

Thank you..

Comment: Are you using rd_! this kind of variable?

Comment: I have tried clean build and invalidate cashes restart.. Its not working.. @ IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: `Ctrl` + click on the variable in android studio. It will show usages. Rename it to something that follows java standards.

Comment: No i don't have any variable like that. when I remove ! this from rd_!=0x7f0e0210; this it shows error is gone. but we cant edit the R.java file so it appears again..@ ajantha

Comment: Thank you.. I have tried but its not showing any usage. No usage foundin project files..@K Neeraj Lal

Comment: any invalid string file names??

Comment: Its not showing used anywhere.. I have not created this. Don't know from where it has come. @Vivek Mishra

Comment: then manually check for each id in your layouts

Comment: But if its not showing used anywhere how it will show in any layout??@ Vivek Mishra

Comment: I mean to say manually check in each layout that all your id's name are proper as R.java is associated with id's from your xml layout

Comment: all are proper . :-(

Comment: got it.. Thank you..@Vivek Mishra

Comment: what and where was it??

Comment: It was there in one of the layouts. I had copied one radio button its id was like that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `!` is valid for Java variable naming.

Comment: I have not named any variable like that.. I don't now from where this error has come..

Comment: @user5669913 `rd_!=0x7f0e0210` this is your code correct? The `!` at the end of `rd_` is not valid Java.

Comment: This I have not coded. Its showing the ID in R.java file..@Eugen Hotaj

Comment: @user5669913 Hmm, where is this R file coming from? Are you sure it's a valid Java file? To the best of my knowledge Java does not allow `!` in variable names. The only thing I can think of is you might be missing some dependency or something that somehow allows this naming to happen (but that's a stretch).